# Network error: The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, file-sharing

I'm receiving this message after getting a list of files. And trying to move a file out of the list. There is no Antivirus software installed on this server.

The server is Win Server 2003 SP2.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is or what the scenario around this error is. I know it's old but this thread comes up in google results for the error you describe.

Comment: I found that I only get this error when using Hostname. If I attempt to access the system by IP address I don't get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.0 installed?

According to the following Microsoft article, the issue may be due to Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.0.  If you have it installed, consider upgrading or removing it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/961293

Comment: No, I've googled this like crazy. No Symantec products at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to copy a large file from a network share to my local hard drive (or access it directly from the parent application) with the same error.

It turned out to be an incorrect message. The real problem was that the network copy was timing out. I succeeded in copying this 4 gig file by using the Windows command-line utility ROBOCOPY, which has a parameter to extend the timeout wait. A command to try might be:

```
robocopy /z /v /w:240 source-dirname target-dirname
```

The robocopy command isn't well documented, but from fighting with it I found that it would not copy individual files, only the contents of a directory to another directory. Flags: /z means "resume on failure, don't restart the copy." /v means "verify the copy once complete." /w:240 means "extend the timeout delay to 4 minutes(240 seconds)."

In my actual copy I threw in the command "/fft" (assume FAT file times) because the docs say that is more reliable and I was desperate to have this stupid transfer finally complete, and "/fp", which displays the percentage complete of the file being copied. (It's a big file, I wanted to get an idea how long the process would take.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the "Robocopy" error "ERROR 64 (0x00000040)" was caused by a faulty HDD in my destination Storage Pool using Storage Spaces (6 x HDDs). I tried many things to solve the problem, but nothing helped.
When I than desperate start to disconnect the hard disks from the storage pool, the first file that always caused the error start to copy and I was able to copy my whole movie library. I was getting the errors trying to backup my movie library and I've got one error on every bigger file, like movie file (.avi .mkv...) interesting is that all other small files were copying without any problems. Because of that, I couldn't figure out what is causing the errors. As soon as I disconnected the defect hard disk, the "Robocopy" did his job.
So, if you guys are stuck with no ideas you may consider checking your hard drives.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the /w option does not affect the timeout delay. It controls how long to wait before resuming transfer following a failure. Default is 30s, I set it to 5. Here is the output:

```
...
 56.5%
2017/01/13 13:41:42 ERROR 64 (0x00000040) Copying File <dir>\TestData_1GB.pst
The specified network name is no longer available.
Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
            Newer               1000.0 m        <dir>\TestData_1GB
 59.1%
2017/01/13 13:42:41 ERROR 64 (0x00000040) Copying File <dir>\TestData_1GB.pst
The specified network name is no longer available.
Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
            Newer               1000.0 m        <dir>\TestData_1GB
 59.1%
2017/01/13 13:42:47 ERROR 64 (0x00000040) Copying File <dir>\TestData_1GB.pst
The specified network name is no longer available.
Waiting 5 seconds... Retrying...
            Newer               1000.0 m        <dir>\TestData_1GB
 62.0%
2017/01/13 13:43:42 ERROR 64 (0x00000040) Copying File <dir>\TestData_1GB.pst
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.